# Fetch Rails i18n translations to be rendered in React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, react-rails

I have a React/Rails application which I am setting up i18n translations. Using rails-i18n and i18n.js gems. I have en.yml and es.yml files for english and spanish. The translations seem to work well for this application. I am able to get the translations rendered in the in the view. However, there is a second React/Redux application which makes api calls to this same backend. Is it possible to use the translations I already have in Rails? If so, what is the best way to set the translations?